# WCF ticket base authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication

I am writing WCF service that uses wsHttpBinding binding, which is not hosted in IIS but in Windows Service.  I  want to have a Login(user,pass) method in service, which will give a ticket to the client if the user is valid.

Can anyone help me to understand how to implement ticket base authentication in WCF? Is there any standard mechanism or I have to implement my own? I also want to store other data for each user in the in the service as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I don't know are there any standard mechanisms or not, but the post here helps me to solve the problem...
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2006/04/23/141.aspx
I just return ticket from login method if the user is valied, and send that token with the message header in every call, which can be checked in other service call