# WCF security implementation design issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I have experience in creating ASP.net/WinForms apps and I want to learn WCF now by creating a simple Task Manager project.

Thank you in advance for reading the incoming block of text. My problem is more one of design than an actual coding issue.

My goal is the following:

- Create a Web Service (using WCF) whose purpose is the management of tasks/todo lists
- The Web Service will allow users to register for an account, create new to do lists, share to do lists with other users etc
- After the Web Service is functional and everything is implemented I want to be able to layer an ASP.NET website on top of it and use the Web Service for the backend

At the moment I have the following:

- 1 console application hosting the web service
- 1 console application (client) used to make to calls to the web service (I test my Web Service this way)

The Web Service application has the following config file (hope I pasted it OK):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Tasker_Server.Properties.Settings.TaskerConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=PROPHET\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tasker;Persist     Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=stf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Tasker_Server.TaskerService" behaviorConfiguration="TaskerServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/TaskerTest/Service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="login" address="username" binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
              contract="Tasker_Server.ITasker" />
        <endpoint name="reg" address="reg" binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Binding2"
              contract="Tasker_Server.Contracts.IRegister" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" receiveTimeout="00:20:00">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="Binding2">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TaskerServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Tasker_Server.CustomValidator, Tasker_Server" />
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And I start the Web Service like this:

```
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TaskerService));

try {
    selfHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service is up... (press <ENTER> to terminate)");
    Console.ReadLine();

    selfHost.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException ce) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ce.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
    selfHost.Abort();
}
```

At the moment I have only two contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Tasker_Server")]
public interface ITasker {
    [OperationContract]
    string CheckCredentials(string username, string password);
}
```

and

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Tasker_Register")]
public interface IRegister {
    [OperationContract]
    string RegisterUser(string username, string password, string email);
}
```

What I tried to accomplish is the following:

1. Offer an unsecured endpoint; clients can invoke this and register an account.
2. Offer a secured endpoint (I use UserName authentication with a custom UserNamePasswordValidator) through which users can "login" and invoke all the operations.

Both these things in my software work right now. I can register a new account through an unsecured endpoint and I can invoke the secure endpoint by providing the correct ClientCredentials in the client.

My questions are the following:

1. From what I understand, by using UserName authentication, the Validation method in my custom validator will be called each time the client invokes a Web Service method (this means that a DB query will run each time to check the credentials as opposed to a website where you login once until your session expires). Is there something fundamentally wrong with doing things this way?
2. I thought of another possible way to manage this (and in a way simulate how a website would work):

   - Use a secure endpoint (UserName authentication) only for an operation similar to a "login"
   - If the credentials are correct I create a new GUID, save it in memory and make an association between an username and that guid.
   - then all the operations will not require UserName authentication but will have an additional parameter (the GUID): if the GUID is in memory and associated with a user then the operation is permitted
   - The logout operation would destroy the GUID in memory.
   - I would assume that I can use SSL on top of this so that the GUID won't be sent in clear
   - does this defeat the purpose of Web Service security and I'm just trying to reinvent the wheel?

Which method would be better? And why?

**Update:** added wrong config file. It was from the client instead of the Web Service. Added the correct one now.

Comment: This. Is. An excellent question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm waiting for someone to post some opinions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with guid is good. See other question [WCF ticket base authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829254/wcf-ticket-base-authentication) and referred post

[WCF Custom Message Headers](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2006/04/23/141.aspx)

UPDATE: Comparison of approaches.

Benefits of the first approach is stateless/sessionless of individual operations. Neither client nor service need to remember details of the previous authentication call. However if the same client does multiple calls, it's better to remember ticket, rather then remember and send username&password each time.
If you concerned about repeated calls to database, you can cache for some time(e.g. 30min) 
 username&password ( or better hash of them) and compare details of new request in cached dictionary before  doing database call.

The second approach required keeping state( I.e. ticket) on the client, so is a little bit more complicated. But it's more secure, because you don't need to remember username&password during the whole session.For your scenario I would prefer ticket approach.

By the way, after login I still recommend to use https (usually performance penalty is not essential) but it prevents network sniffer to steal the ticket and use it to do some malicious actions instead of the user.

Comment: Pretty nice. I might end up doing just that. I am still wondering however what the advantage/disadvantage between the two would be (besides the obvious db call).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your update. I'll go with a simple custom ticketing like you described for now. Also thank you for mentioning https; was planning on doing it at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

2 is a reasonable idea. Its called Window Identity Framework.

The only real difference from what you propose is that in a Federated security model you have the authentication separated from the application. In WIF you authenticate to a trusted authority which issues a token (your GUID). Encrypted within the token are a set of claims (permitted operations). The client passes in the token as a part of its WCF call, the claims are transferred to the security principle, and suddenly your application is doing role based security without any knowledge WCF.

The disadvantage of WIF is that it is complicated and can take quite a bit of ramp up time.

The advantage to WIF is that its written by security experts. If you are actually building a commercial application that will handle money or sensitive data you should use WIF for this reason alone.

This is an [older article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx) but a nice motivation to the ideas. And then there's [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx).

Comment: Windows Identity Foundation allow authentication to be implemented in the same application, but for the described scenarios I think, it's overkill.

Comment: +1 for telling me about WIF (which I personally didn't know existed) but as Michael said it is overkill for what I am doing right now. I will keep it in mind though for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not achieve what you want [using sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) in WCF?

Comment: What I want is very close if not identical to what Michael Freidgeim suggested. I am still looking for a some pros and cons regarding to my questions section.